# How can I connect a post to user and display that user and post data in a Custom cell in TableView using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, post, denormalization

I am building a social media app and since I wasn't able to solve this by myself, I need help.

I have connected my Xcode project to the Firebase and made it possible for my users to register/sign in and publish Posts to the Firebase which are then shown all together in one group TableView but none of the data is connected to the user which posted that Post. The idea is that it looks similar to Instagram posts, but every post in my app would have to include only: Photo and Caption(optional) which are part of a Post Class, and CraftName which is a part of User Class. I believe that the problem lies in "denormalization" and incorrect populating of tableView.

Here is a photo of my Firebase tree which currently has 2 users signed in. One has posted 1 Post, and another has posted 2 Posts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP7cK.png

I successfully register Users( with email, username and CraftName) to firebase database and I have made it possible for them to sign in and sign out so I believe the problem is somewhere else to look. I have also made it possible to post a Post to Firebase which includes Photo and Caption and to populate the tableView with that two objects. Only thing left is to connect user with it's Post and while displaying the Post, provide that User's CraftName as a TextView above the Post.

This is AuthService class which deals with registration

```
static func register(username: String, email: String, password: String, craftName: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:  { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)

            return
        }
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        self.setUserInformation(username: username, email: email,  craftName: craftName, uid: uid, onSuccess: onSuccess)

    })
}
```

This is a registration class

```
@IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    AuthService.register(username: usernameTextField.text!, email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, craftName: craftNameTextField.text!, onSuccess: {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerToTabBar", sender: self)
    }, onError: {error in
         ProgressHUD.showError(error!)
        })
    }
}

//Stvaranje reference na Firebase Realtime bazu podataka i spremanje svih podataka svakog korisnika zasebno u tu bazu podataka
static func setUserInformation(username: String, email: String, craftName: String, uid: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void){

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersReference = ref.child("users")
    let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid)
    newUserReference.setValue(["username": username, "email": email, "craftName": craftName])

    onSuccess()
}
```

}

This is my User Class

```
struct User {
    var username: String?
    var email: String?
    var craftName: String

    init(craftNameString: String, emailString : String, usernameString: String){
        craftName = craftNameString
        username = usernameString
        email = emailString
    }
}
```

This is my Post Class

```
class Post {

    var caption: String?
    var photoUrl: String?
    var numberOfClaps: Int?

    init(captionText: String, photoUrlString: String) {
        caption = captionText
        photoUrl = photoUrlString     
    }
}
```

This is my Post custom cell class

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var captionTextViev: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var craftNameTextField: UITextView!

    var post : Post! {
        didSet{
            self.updatePostUI()
        }
    }
    var user : User! {
        didSet{
            self.updateUserUI()
        }
    }

    func updatePostUI() {

        captionTextViev.text = post.caption

    }
    func updateUserUI(){
        craftNameTextField.text = user.craftName
    }
 }
```

Now when my users are Registered, they can post a Post in CameraClass.

```
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let postImg = selectedImage, let imageData = postImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {
        let photoIDString = NSUUID().uuidString
        print(photoIDString)
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOT_REF).child("posts").child(photoIDString)

        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }else {

                        if let photoURL = url?.absoluteString{
                            self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoURL)
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }


func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let postsReference = ref.child("posts")
    let userUID = postsReference.child(uid)
    let newPostID = userUID.child(userUID.childByAutoId().key!)
    newPostID.setValue(["photoUrl": photoUrl, "caption": captionTextView.text!], withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        ProgressHUD.show("Uspješno ste objavili fotografiju")
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.clean()

        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    })
```

This is my HomeViewController in which is the tableView that is supposed to display Posts

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var posts = [Post]()

struct Storyboard {

    static let postCellDefaultHeight : CGFloat = 578.0
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = Storyboard.postCellDefaultHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    loadPosts()
}

//Function which is supposed to retrieve data from database and populate the TableView
func loadPosts() {

            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let posts = ref.child("posts")
            posts.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                    for currentUser in (snapshot.children) {
                        let cUSer = currentUser as! DataSnapshot
                        for postInfo in (cUSer.children) {
                            let postSnap = postInfo as! DataSnapshot
                            let dict = postSnap.value as? [String: Any]
                            let captionText = dict!["caption"] as! String
                            let photoUrlString = dict!["photoUrl"] as! String
                            let post = Post(captionText: captionText, photoUrlString: photoUrlString)

                            self.posts.append(post)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It looks like this right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8t8M.jpg

This is how I would like it to look: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZjMJ.jpg